# ASP .NET Web API SignalR - compile something when connecting, high CPU usage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, signalr

I have built ASP .NET Web API with SignalR to handle chat feature. The problem is, when client start SignalR connection, the application start some compilation (csc.exe or VBCSCompiler.exe), take 100% CPU usage and block other requests. What is more, the problem exist on all environments except my own and does not happen on all page refreshes - sometimes it connects without compile.

[image: CPU usage]

So far I have tried:

- Remove my code which handle connections (OnConnected, OnDisconnected, OnReconnected)
- Check differences in Web.config files between environments
- Block csc.exe or VBCSCompiler.exe with permissions.
- Try different SignalR transport method. LongPolling works the same way
- Check SignalR connection log on client and server side (here you can see how long it takes to negotiate - 17s)
  [image: SignalR client log]
- Check what process take so much time with a profiler. Here you can see StartApplication method which run some compile methods.
  [image: Profiler]

Do you have any idea what more should I check or do with that case?

Comment: Is this release, or are you debugging the code?

Comment: This is release.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution. 
The problem was that logs was saving in bin folder. Because of that, every entry in log file caused app pool recycle. **You cannot keep your logs in *bin* folder!** 
In my case, there was some info entry during connection, and because of that my application was compiling something on almost every request.